# Why isn't this catching the error

Tags: c#, error-handling

When the user types in a string instead of the integer it gives me and error and crashes the console.  I don't understand how to catch this error.  What I want it to do if this error happens is to skip the player's turn.

```
Console.Write("Row (1-3): ");
int UserRowChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
try {  }
catch (InvalidCastException e) { ThrowError("You typed a string instead of an integer.  You've lost your turn."); Console.ReadKey(); RunGame(T1, CurrentPlayer, Winner); }
if (UserRowChoice < 1 || UserRowChoice > 3)
{
    ThrowError("You either typed a number that was less than 1 or greater than 3.  You've lost your turn.");
    Console.ReadKey();
    RunGame(T1, CurrentPlayer, Winner);
}
```

Comment: You don't have anything inside your `try` block, so nothing is being caught. You need, `try { UserRowChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine()); } catch ...`. Of course, then `int UserRowChoice;` needs to be defined before and outside of that block.

Comment: This is not a simple typo - it's the concept that seems to be misunderstood.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Never use `Convert.ToInt32` on user input.
Use `Int.TryParse` instead.
This is the perfect example of a [vexing exception.](https://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/)

> **Vexing** exceptions are the result of unfortunate design decisions. Vexing exceptions are thrown in a completely non-exceptional circumstance, and therefore must be caught and handled all the time.
>
> The classic example of a vexing exception is Int32.Parse, which throws if you give it a string that cannot be parsed as an integer. But the 99% use case for this method is transforming strings input by the user, which could be any old thing, and therefore it is in no way exceptional for the parse to fail.

The `Convert.ToInt32` overload that accepts a string as an argument simply calls `int.Parse` inside - [see it's source code:](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/convert.cs)

```
public static int ToInt32(String value) {
    if (value == null)
        return 0;
    return Int32.Parse(value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

Therefor it's just as vexing as using `int.Parse` and should be avoided.
The rule of thumb is to not use exceptions for things you can easily check using code - exceptions are for exceptional things - mainly things you can't control in your code such as network availability and stuff like that - and a user entering `adsf` instead of `12` is not exceptional at all.

To answer your question directly,
The reason you are not catching the exception is because your `Convert.ToInt32` is not inside your `try` block.

To actually catch the exception your code should have looked like this:

```
Console.Write("Row (1-3): ");
int UserRowChoice = 0;
try 
{  
    UserRowChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
catch (InvalidCastException e) { ThrowError("You typed a string instead of an integer.  You've lost your turn."); Console.ReadKey(); RunGame(T1, CurrentPlayer, Winner); }
if (UserRowChoice < 1 || UserRowChoice > 3)
{
    ThrowError("You either typed a number that was less than 1 or greater than 3.  You've lost your turn.");
    Console.ReadKey();
    RunGame(T1, CurrentPlayer, Winner);
}
```

However, as I wrote before, don't use `Convert.ToInt32` - use `int.TryParse` instead:

```
Console.Write("Row (1-3): ");
int UserRowChoice = 0;
if(int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out UserRowChoice))
{  
    if (UserRowChoice < 1 || UserRowChoice > 3)
    {
        ThrowError("You either typed a number that was less than 1 or greater than 3.  You've lost your turn.");
        Console.ReadKey();
        RunGame(T1, CurrentPlayer, Winner);
    }
}
else
{
    ThrowError("You typed a string instead of an integer.  You've lost your turn."); 
    Console.ReadKey(); 
    RunGame(T1, CurrentPlayer, Winner); 
}
```

Comment: "Never use `Convert.ToIn32`" Care to explain this quote? There are plenty of times one could use that without issue...You only need `TryParse` when you rely on the `bool` it returns to indicate a successful parse...

Comment: You might as well say "don't use `Int.Parse`" since `Convert.ToInt32` is just a wrapper around that. Its true that TryParse is usually the right answer though

Comment: because a user entering a string that can't be parsed to an int is not an exceptional situation. This is the perfect example of a vexing exception.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Sure, it's pretty much always wrong to use `int.Parse` *to parse input provided by a human user*.  There are lots of situations that involve parsing strings that *aren't* generated from human user input and that are most properly parsed using `int.Parse`.

Comment: @Servy the first line in my answer is "Never use `Convert.ToInt32` **on user input.**" Perhaps I should bold it in the answer as well, what do you think?

Comment: @Servy I've encountered my share of strings that where suppose to contain integer-parseable values from 3rd party web API's that ended up containing letters and other junk. I don't trust machine input for a long time now. not even if the source is from my own code.

Comment: Upvote, great answer with high verbosity

Comment: @ZoharPeled The question is what you can *do* about it.  If you're in a position to just re-prompt for input to hopefully get correct input, then it makes sense to check the value and re-prompt if it's bad.  But if the bad input leaves you with no realistic options except to throw and have your particular procedure end because there is no means of recovery (a common enough situation) you want to use `int.Parse`.

Comment: @servy I would still rather use tryParse and if it return false not continue executing the method.

Comment: Hopefully ThrowError doesn't... Throw an exception. Otherwise OP is still doomed. (obviously it's their code, not yours). Good money says that RunGame is the name of the enclosing method in the OP.. If throw error doesn't actually throw then its possible it'll Stackoverflow eventually.

Comment: @ZoharPeled But then how does the caller know that the method didn't actually work properly?  You put it into the position of thinking that the method worked correctly when in fact it did not.

Comment: It depends. usually, when the caller needs to know, the method returns a value - that value might be a composite value with a built in indication of success / fail.

Answer (score 1):

Your `try` block is not surrounding the code that could raise an `InvalidCastException`. Try this:

```
Console.Write("Row (1-3): ");
int UserRowChoice;
try 
{  
    UserRowChoice = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
}
catch (InvalidCastException e) { ThrowError("You typed a string instead of an integer.  You've lost your turn."); Console.ReadKey(); RunGame(T1, CurrentPlayer, Winner); }
if (UserRowChoice < 1 || UserRowChoice > 3)
{
    ThrowError("You either typed a number that was less than 1 or greater than 3.  You've lost your turn.");
    Console.ReadKey();
    RunGame(T1, CurrentPlayer, Winner);
}
```

Comment: The contents of the catch block (from the OP, of course, but copied here) are most certainly incorrect and I'd bet money (even without seeing it all) they're calling the same method they're declared in (recursively) and will eventually Stackoverflow... Assuming that ThrowError() doesn't throw an exception itself (in which case, it's all still wrong anyways)

Answer (score 0):

try to check the value type before passing it to whatever you want to do.

```
string line = Console.ReadLine();
int value;
if (int.TryParse(line, out value))
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Integer here!");
    }
else
     {
         Console.WriteLine("Not an integer!");
     }
```

this will return if the value is int or not !!
If it's an int, continue with whatever you want, else, ask the use again.